# Struts reflection for boolean java variable

Tags: java, oop, struts2, java-7

I wish to add a param in one of the actions in Struts. That param is boolean and private
Ex-
Struts code

```
<action name="check" class="CityAction" method="dpCheck">
<result name="review" type="redirect" >
<param name="cityChanged">${cityChanged}</param>
</result>
```

Java Action

```
public class CityAction{
private boolean check = true;
public boolean isCheck(){
return check
}
public boolean setCheck(boolean value){
check = value;
}    
}
```

My question - can struts access this private boolean variable ?
For some other fields, I checked the documentation that we need to have a method that starts with get and the variable Name check - getCheck(), but things may be different for boolean variables.
What method name should I use here to make boolean private variable to be accessed by struts?

Comment: What happened when you tried it? The type of the variable is irrelevant (and whether or not it's private *used* to be irrelevant, but that may have changed), but exposing via JavaBean naming conventions works for booleans just like anything else.

Comment: isCheck or getCheck -> which one of these is called by struts ?